# Will Google Maps Geocoding API V2 stop working on 3/8/13?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

We received a notice that said:

"The Google Maps API V2 was deprecated on March 8, 2010 and will continue to work until March 8, 2013. After that date, we will no longer offer support for this API and it will be eventually decommissioned."

Does this mean it will completely stop working after 3/8/2013 or will it possibly still work but no longer be supported?

Thanks!
John

Comment: you better ask this in the [mailing-group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-maps-js-api-v3)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this has been answered on the [geo developers blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/an-update-on-geocoding-api-v2.html).

They've extended the lifetime of the API until 8 September 2013 after which time it is going to be turned off completely.

Answer (score 1):

> The Google Maps Geocoding API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of March 8, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until Mar 8, 2013.

As far as I understand it will COMPLETELY stop working after 3/8/2013. That is the reason they gave 3 years worth of time to upgrade from v2 to v3.